# Superclass/Subclass methods

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have a situation

```
public class Animal
{
   String noise;

  public String makeNoise()
  {
      return noise;
  }
}
```

Then there will be a subclass with the concrete definition of the noise.

```
public class Dog extends Animal{
   String noise = "woof";
}
```

also

```
public class Cat extends Animal{
   String noise = "meow";
}
```

What I want to do is

```
 Animal cat = new Cat();
 cat.makeNoise();  // This will be 'meow'
```

and

```
Animal dog = new Dog();
dog.makeNoise();  // This will be 'woof'
```

Basically, I don't want to repeat the makeNoise() method when I create an animal. However, this will not work. (Noise is an empty string)

I could use a static object like

```
static String NoiseDog = "woof"
static String NoiseCat = "meow"
```

but then again I have to write the makeNoise() method for each animal. Is there a better way to architect this?

Comment: Set the noise member of the super class in the constructor on each of the sub classes. You only need to implement makeNoise() in the super.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to force all sub-classes of `Animal` to have a `noise` defined, you can enforce that in the constructor:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    private final String noise;

    public Animal(final String noise) {
        this.noise = noise;
    }

    public String makeNoise() {
        return noise;
    }
}
```

Then Dog:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
    public Dog() {
        super("woof");
    }
}
```

And Cat:

```
public class Cat extends Animal {
    public Cat() {
        super("meow");
    }
}
```

And to test it out:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Animal dog = new Dog();
        System.out.println(dog.makeNoise());
        final Animal cat = new Cat();
        System.out.println(cat.makeNoise());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
woof
meow
```

Comment: Thanks for this. In my real world example, there are 5 different parameters which need to be set differently for each class. So not really easy to pass 5 values in the constructor.

Comment: @user2689782 If you have 5 parameters to pass to `Animal`, you could wrap those parameters into another class `AnimalCharacteristics` and pass that to `Animal`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Cat extends Animal{
   String noise = "meow";
}
```

This creates an instance variable named "noise" that hides the superclass variable.
Instead, you need this to set the superclass value:

```
public class Cat extends Animal{
   public Cat() {
      noise = "meow";
   }
}
```

Comment: I did not understand this?

Comment: @user2689782 this sets the String noise in the superclass to "meow", giving you the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `Animal` class abstract. This way, there can be no such thing as an `Animal` object which calls `makeNoise`.

Then, set the `noise` String to a value within the constructor of each subclass as appropriate to that animal's sound.

Comment: Same problem. I have a large number of parameters which are specific to each subclass.

Comment: If they're specific to the subclass, then you don't have to pass them to the constructor as parameters. Just set the values in the constructor body.

Comment: Set the values in the constructor of the superclass? Or subclass?

Comment: Each subclass. So in the `Dog` constructor you'd have `noise = "Woof"` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could implement an interface like so:

Animal:

```
public interface Animal {
    public String makeNoise();
}
```

Dog:

```
public class Dog implements Animal {
    public String makeNoise() {
        return "woof";
    }
}
```

Cat:

```
public class Cat implements Animal {
    public String makeNoise() {
        return "meow";
    }
}
```

Test:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal dog = new Dog();
        System.out.println(dog.makeNoise());
        Animal cat = new Cat();
        System.out.println(cat.makeNoise());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
woof
meow
```

Comment: In this case, I have to define the makeNoise() method in each class. I am trying to get away from that.